# Printing all key values in a nested hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have the following hash:

```
doc = {"house"=>{"Team 1"=>0, "Team 2"=>0, "Team 3"=>0, "Team 4"=>0}}
```

I am trying to print the "Team" keys.

For example:

```
Team 1
Team 2
Team 3
Team 4
```

I tried using `doc.values` but this returns an array `[{"Team 1"=>0, "Team 2"=>0, "Team 3"=>0, "Team 4"=>0}]`. Which means I can't do `doc.values.keys`.

I tried using a for loop, but somehow it prints the value this way instead:

```
Team 1
0
Team 2
0
..
```

Is there a way to to get these keys?

Comment: `{"Team 1"=>0, "Team 2"=>0, "Team 3"=>0, "Team 4"=>0}` isn't an `Array`, it's a `Hash`. `doc.values` should return an array with one element in it, where the one element is that hash. You could get the keys of it using `doc.values.first.keys`.

Comment: What is `doc`??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
puts doc["house"].keys
```

If you don't necessarily know what the first key will be, this also works:

```
puts doc.values.flat_map(&:keys)
```

Just for fun, here's a third approach, if you know there'll always be just the one outer key:

```
puts doc[doc.keys.first].keys
```

That what you're after? Hope it helps - let me know if you've any questions!

Comment: Slipped my mind I could have accessed the document keys directly! Great answer.

Comment: Thanks, happy to help :)

Comment: The last one is strange, `puts doc.values.first.keys` seems strictly better. And a somewhat funny one: `puts doc.first.last.key`